# NOT EXISTS expression with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL statement with a `NOT EXISTS` operator to insert multiple records,  except where those records exist already. Here's the code to build the query:

```
INSERT INTO OID_TBL (EMPID, OID, DETAILS) 
SELECT @EMPID, OID_PCC, @DETAILS 
FROM UAT_TBL WHERE BSOURCE = @BSOURCE
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT EMPID, OID, DETAILS FROM OID_TBL WHERE EMPID = @EMPID)
```

Unfortunately, it's not producing the results I need.

#### Given:

```
@EMPDI = "11111111"  
@BSOURSE = "A"
@DETAILS = GETDATE()
```

#### UAT_TBL

```
[BSOURCE] [OID]       
A         MNL123    
A         MNL124    
A         MNL125    
G         MNL123    
G         MNL124    
G         MNL125
```

#### OID_TBL

```
11111111    MNL123   2019-01-10
```

#### Actual result:

```
11111111    MNL123   2019-01-10
```

#### Desired Result:

```
11111111    MNL123   2020-05-18
11111111    MNL124   2020-05-18
11111111    MNL125   2020-05-18
```

How can I fix this to produce the desired result?

Comment: Aside: The _select list_ within an `exists` subquery is a placeholder, i.e. it's required by the syntax but unused semantically. It can be `42`, `NULL`, `1 / 0` or, if you want to irritate a _particular_ subset of humanity, `*`. Putting a carefully crafted list of columns there serves only to perplex those who stumble across it later. A lofty goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the `NOT EXISTS` expression selects three columns. There is no matching done on those columns. For each row in the main `SELECT`, if **any** results are returned by nested expression for the `NOT EXISTS` query, the conditions fails and the row will be skipped.

Therefore, if you need to match by `OID` also, you need that as part of the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM OID_TBL WHERE EMPID=@EMPID AND OID=UAT_TBL.OID_PCC)
```

If the `Details` column matters, include a condition for that in the `WHERE` clause, too. And speaking of `Details`, that column looks really **broken** right now. If you want to store dates there, you need a real `datetime` column.

Finally, I'd remove the separate input variable for `@DETAILS` and just use `getdate()` or `current_timestamp` directly in the SQL.

Comment: I've just figured it out...Thank you everyone. Here's the query:  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO OID_TBL (EMPID,OID,DETAILS)
                                        SELECT @EMPID,OID_PCC,@DETAILS
                                        FROM UAT_TBL
                                        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT EMPID,OID,DETAILS FROM OID_TBL WHERE EMPID=@EMPID AND OID_TBL.OID=UAT_TBL.OID_PCC)"